# OperationalError at / no such table: users_user

Tags: python, django, django-models

I had a model Profile which was an extension to my User model which was the ForeignKey of my Post model, but I changed it to an AbstractUser and now if I try migrating or running and refreshing the page the server I get an error.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500,null=True)
```

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import reverse


class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-details', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'posts',
    'users',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
```

error message after I try migrating

```
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, posts, sessions, users
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Projects/DNF/Project/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/user/Projects/DNF/Project/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 96, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 295, in handle
    pre_migrate_apps = pre_migrate_state.apps
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 566, in apps
    return StateApps(self.real_apps, self.models)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 637, in __init__
    raise ValueError("\n".join(error.msg for error in errors))
ValueError: The field admin.LogEntry.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'users.user', but app 'users' doesn't provide model 'user'.
The field posts.Post.author was declared with a lazy reference to 'users.user', but app 'users' doesn't provide model 'user'.
The field users.Profile.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'users.user', but app 'users' doesn't provide model 'user'.
```

Comment: I've seen that question but the answer didn't help...

Comment: did you try migrating your User model first and after it changing post model Author?

Comment: I've deleted the database and did that, now it is working.

Comment: try changing order of ```'posts'``` and ```'users'``` in *INSTALLED_APPS*

Comment: It is already working after I deleted the migrations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I easily solved it by deleting all the migration files in the migrations folder except the **init**.py file. And also delete db.sqlite3. Now run the following commands : python manage.py makemigrations and then python manage.py migrate. Now you'll have to create the super user once again, so for this just type the following commmand : python manage.py createsuperuser. Then it will prompt for username, email and password, so enter your credentials and all will continue to work properly once again I hope that this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

try to directly reference the User model, not through settings

change the foreign key field to this:

```
author = models.ForeignKey("users.User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

To have a reference to the User model, you should not do through settings directly instead you can use `get_user_model()` function. This function will return the currently active User model of project( the custom User model if one is specified, or User otherwise).

So change the foreign key field of your `Post` model like below:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    ...
```

Reference: [**`get_user_model()`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model)